# Formatting table for tableau proof

Tags: tables

Hello I am kinda new to latex and I want to create a table for a tableau proof, it should look like this, but I have no clue how to achieve it.

[image: The formatting I want to achieve for the tableau]

Edit: I figured out that I can do something similar to this with the multirow package in combination with noraml tables :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the new `tabularray` package ([CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)). In my opinion, it is more flexible than using `multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myT}{\mathbf{t}}
\newcommand{\myF}{\mathbf{f}}

\begin{tblr}{
        colspec=r*{7}{c}l,
        rowsep=0pt,
        column{1,3,5,7}={rightsep=0pt},
        vline{3,5,7},
    }
    (1) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: \exists x (F(x) \land S(x,a))$ &&&&&&& Ann.$(\delta)$ \\
    (2) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: \lnot F(h)$ &&&&&&& Ann. \\
    (3) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: \forall x \forall y (S(x,y)\supset M(x,y))$ &&&&&&& Ann.$(\gamma)$ \\
    (4) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: \exists x[M(x,a) \land \forall y (M(y,a) \supset y=x)]$ &&&&&&& Ann.$(\delta)$ \\
    (5) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myF: \lnot M(h,a)$ &&&&&&& Ann. \\
    \cline{2-Y}
    (6) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: F(b) \land S(b,a)$ &&&&&&& von 1 \\
    \cline{2-Y}
    (7) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: M(c,a) \land \forall y(M(y,a) \supset y=c)$ &&&&&&& von 4 \\
    \cline{2-Y}
    (8) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: M(c,a)$ &&&&&&& von 7 \\
    (9) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: \forall y(M(y,a) \supset y=c)$ &&&&&&& von 7$(\gamma)$ \\
    \cline{2-Y}
    (10) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: F(b)$ &&&&&&& von 6 \\
    (11) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: S(b,a)$ &&&&&&& von 6 \\
    \cline{2-Y}
    (12) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: \forall y(S(b,y) \supset M(b,y))$ &&&&&&& von 3$(\gamma)$ \\
    \cline{2-Y}
    (13) & \SetCell[c=7]{c} $\myT: S(b,a) \supset M(b,a)$ &&&&&&& von 12 \\
    \cline{2-Y}
    (14) & \SetCell[r=9]{h} {$\myF: S(b,a)$ \\ $\times (11/14)$} & (15) & \SetCell[c=5]{c} $\myT: M(b,a)$ &&&&& von 13 \\
    \cline{4-Y}
    && (16) & \SetCell[c=5]{c} $\myT: M(b,a) \supset b=c$ &&&&& von 9 \\
    \cline{4-Y}
    && (17) & \SetCell[r=7]{h} {$\myF: M(b,a)$ \\ $\times (15/17)$} & (18) & \SetCell[c=3]{c} $\myT: b=c$ &&& von 16 \\
    \cline{6-Y}
    &&&& (19) & \SetCell[c=3]{c} $\myT: M(h,a)$ &&& von 5 \\
    \cline{6-Y}
    &&&& (20) & \SetCell[c=3]{c} $\myT: M(h,a) \supset h=c$ &&& von 9 \\
    \cline{6-Y}
    &&&& (21) & \SetCell[r=4]{h} {$\myF: M(h,a)$ \\ $\times (19/21)$} & (22) & $\myT: h=c$ & von 20 \\
    \cline{8-Y}
    &&&&&& (23) & $\myF: F(h)$ & von 2 \\
    \cline{8-Y}
    &&&&&& (24) & $\myF: F(c)$ & $S=:22\rightarrow23$ \\
    \cline{8-Y}
    &&&&&& (25) & $\myT: F(c)$ & $S=:18\rightarrow10$ \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: table output]